# how to change the color of decimals points in php

Tags: php, html, css

how can I change the colors of ONLY decimals of a number in PHP?
this is my function for formatting numbers

```
function formatNumber($input, $decimals = 'auto', $prefix = '', $suffix = '') {

    $input = floatval($input);
    $absInput = abs($input);
    if ($decimals === 'auto') {
        if ($absInput >= 0.01) {
            $decimals = 2;
        } elseif (0.0001 <= $absInput && $absInput < 0.01) {
            $decimals = 4;
        } elseif (0.000001 <= $absInput && $absInput < 0.0001) {
            $decimals = 6;
        } elseif ($absInput < 0.000001) {
            $decimals = 8;
        }
    }

 if($input>1000000000000000){
        $result = ROUND(($input/1000000000000000),2).' TH ';
    }elseif($input>1000000000000){
        $result = ROUND(($input/1000000000000),2).'  T ';
    }elseif($input>1000000000){
        $result = ROUND(($input/1000000000),2).'  B ';
    }elseif($input>1000000) {
        $result = ROUND(($input / 1000000), 2) . '  M ';
    } else {
        $result  = number_format($input, $decimals, config('decimal-separator','.'), config('thousand-separator', ',')) ;
    }
    return ($prefix ? $prefix : '') . $result. ($suffix ? $suffix : '');

}
```

and I use it like that

```
<?php echo formatNumber($chart['assist'], 2)?>
```

i want my decimals with a different color... can i use css there or add classes?

Comment: CSS can't do that but you could use javascript client side to accomplish it. Alternately you need to manipulate that string output in PHP and add an HTML tag like a `<span>`.

Comment: i suggest use a custom CSS for change this

Comment: please check this for php method http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/csscolor/

Comment: @Tegito123 CSS is not able to work on specific characters. It works on elements in the DOM. You can't select the `.` (periods) in a blurb of text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of what I meant in my comment by manipulate the string:

```
<?php
$n = 123.456;

$whole = floor($n);      //  123
$fraction = $n - $whole; // .456

//echo str_replace('.', '<span class="colorme">.</span>', $n);
echo $whole . '<span class="colorme">.</span>' . substr($fraction, strpos($fraction, '.')+1);
```

//Simply do a string replace on the decimal point.

**UPDATED** break out parts, concatenate.

A client side approach with Javascript (with some jQuery) would be something like:

```
$('#myDiv').each(function () {
  $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\./g, '<span class="colorme">.</span>'));

  //or decimal point and decimal number part...
  $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\.([0-9]+)/g, '<span class="colorme">.$1</span>'));
});
```

Remember that other locales don't always use `.` for divider.

Comment: Just seconding that string replace to wrap with a span and class works very well.

Comment: my bad bro... i want decimals numbers i mean 123.456 (.456 will be in different color) and the numbers is not stable it will change

Comment: Ah man! You made me copy and paste two lines :) Now you know two approaches.

Comment: yo! in your javascript you didn't consider I want the numbers after . would be colored too how can I do that?

Comment: i've used your js like this `$('.price').each(function () {
  $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\./g, '<span class="decimals">.</span>'));
});` but i want a range of number from 0 to 999 would be colored too

Comment: `$(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\.([0-9]+)/g, '<span class="colorme">.$1</span>'));` https://jsfiddle.net/xterdwLm/

Comment: If you're worried about locales, why not do `$dec_point =  '.';// whatever you need it to be $wraped_dec_point = "<span class='dec_point'>{$dec_point}</span>";  $number = number_format (  $some_number , $decimal_places , $wraped_dec_point , $some_thousands_sep = "," );` I'm sure there is a locale extension to get a given locale's decimal point that you could then plug in for `$dec_point` before wrapping it.

Answer (score 0):

So with your existing code, you could do something like:

```
 $dec_point = config('decimal-separator','.');
 $wrapped_dec_point = "<span class='dec_point'>{$dec_point}</span>";
 $result  = number_format($input, $decimals, $wrapped_dec_point, config('thousand-separator', ',')) ;
```

and then of course, for your CSS, you would just need

```
.dec_point {
     color: magenta;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is shorter solution

```
$n = 123.456;
$nums = explode(".",$n);
echo $nums[0] . '<span class="colorme">.' . $nums[1] . '</span>';
```